# simple REPL output formatting (xstring and special characters)

Tags: verbatim, xstring

I want to copy/paste REPL transcripts into an environment and get minimal highlighting of the input.

Expected result:

```
\begin{repl}
> foo
bar
> baz < quux
fnord
\end{repl}
```

should produce something like

`>`**`foo`**
`bar`
`>`**`baz < quux`**
`fnord`

(i.e. verbatim-like environment, user input is bold, all output (including the prompt `>`) is normal.)

---

I *thought* this should be easy to do with `fancyvrb` and `xstring`, however the best thing I could get working still has problems:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{tgcursor} % default fixed font doesn't bold(?)
\renewcommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}[1]{%
  \IfBeginWith{#1}{!}{> \textbf{\StrGobbleLeft{#1}{2}}}{#1}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{Verbatim}
! foo
bar
! baz < quux
fnord
\end{Verbatim}
\end{document}
```

outputs

`>`**`foo`**
`bar`
`>`**`baz ␣quux`**
`fnord`

---

0.  Is this completely the wrong approach or generally going in the right direction?  (If wrong:  Ignore the following questions and just suggest a better way.)

1. `\IfBeginWith` will not compare `>`, so this example uses `!` and replaces it in the output.  (This affects all common prompt characters (`>`, `#`, `$`, `%`).  I looked through [the xstring documentation](http://tug.ctan.org/macros/generic/xstring/xstring_doc_en.pdf) and while §3.1.* states that `#` and `%` might be problematic, from my reading `>` should be fine.)

   ➜ Can this be fixed / made to work with `>` (and possibly the others as well)?
2. `<` mis-behaves in the input.  It produces a warning

   ```
   ! Undefined control sequence.
   <->\leavevmode \kern \z@ \char `\<
   ```

   and depending on other unknown factors may or may not produce the correct character in the output PDF.  (It prints fine in my "full" document (still produces the warning), but the MWE above turns it into a `␣`.  I tried adding some likely candidate packages… no idea what's "fixing" this.)  Changing `\FancyVerbFormatLine` to

   ```
   \IfBeginWith{\detokenize{#1}}{!}{\textbf{#1}}{#1}
   ```

   gets rid of the warning, so this is again `xstring`-related.

   ➜ What's going wrong here and how do I fix it?
3. (non-essential)  While `fancyvrb` allows to define custom verbatim environments with `\DefineVerbatimEnvironment`, `\FancyVerbFormatLine` seems to affect all variants.

   ➜ Is there an *easy* way to make that affect only my custom verbatim environment?  (If there's only a hard way, that's not worth the effort.)

Comment: Welcome to [tex.se]!  Have you looked at the `listings` package?

Comment: @AndrewSwann Yes, I'm aware of the various listing and program output packages – they generally do too much (I don't want line numbers, no (accidental) highlighting, no program execution, no …) and yet they're still inflexible. In the case of `listings`, `\lstset{basicstyle=\ttfamily,morecomment=[l][keywordstyle]{> }}` gets me roughly what I have now, but it also highlights the prompt (which I want to avoid). With `listings` I see no way to improve on that and get what I want, with my approach from above I _know_ that it's possible, I just get problems with "special" characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently `xstring` has problems with removing the space (which however is not really needed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tgcursor} % default fixed font has no bold

\ExplSyntaxOn
\RenewDocumentCommand{\FancyVerbFormatLine}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { \tl_head:n { #1 } } { > }
   { > \bfseries \tl_tail:n { #1 } }
   { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{Verbatim}
> foo
bar
> baz < quux >> foo
fnord
\end{Verbatim}

\end{document}
```

Note you can use `>`, which you can't with `xstring` because in a `Verbatim` environment `>` is active; the `\str_if_eq:nnTF` comparison is category code agnostic.

[image]

If you need to use the standard `Verbatim` command (and even if you don't), a different environment can be used:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fancyvrb}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{tgcursor} % default fixed font has no bold

\newenvironment{shell}
 {\VerbatimEnvironment
  \let\FancyVerbFormatLine\shellformatline
  \Verbatim}
 {\endVerbatim}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand{\shellformatline}{m}
 {
  \str_if_eq_x:nnTF { \tl_head:n { #1 } } { > }
   { > \bfseries \tl_tail:n { #1 } }
   { #1 }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{shell}
> foo
bar
> baz < quux >> foo
fnord
\end{shell}

\end{document}
```